# Flutter RotationTransition on Navigate with a half spin

Tags: animation, flutter

In my app I'm trying to animate the leading appbar icon to spin when the user navigates to another page. Basically I'm trying to create exactly the same animation as in [this video](https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host-backup/mio-design%2Fassets%2F0B3T7oTWa3HiFcHBDaTlreHdVZGc%2Fitem-selection-selecting-items.mp4) from the material design specification.

I managed to make the icon spin on navigation, using a `Hero` with a `RotationTransition`. Currently, however, the icon is spinning a whole circle. I'm quite sure I have to provide another `Animation<double>` to the `turns` parameter of `RotationTransition`, but I got lost in AnimationControllers and vsyncs.

How do I make the icon spin a half circle? And how to control the spinning speed/duration?

BTW. If there is an easier way to make the icon spin on navigation, suggestions are welcome. Also, in the video, on forward and back navigation the icon spins to the same side. Is that possible, using `Navigator.pop()`?

Sample code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Hero(
          tag: "mytag",
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            onPressed: null,
          ),
          // Magic happens here
          flightShuttleBuilder: (
            BuildContext flightContext,
            Animation<double> animation,
            HeroFlightDirection flightDirection,
            BuildContext fromHeroContext,
            BuildContext toHeroContext,
          ) {
            return RotationTransition(
              turns: animation,
              child: Material(
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                shadowColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                shape: CircleBorder(),
                child: toHeroContext.widget
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("To second"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              PageRouteBuilder(
                pageBuilder: 
                  (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => SecondPage()
              )
            );
          },
        ),
      )
    );
  }

}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Hero(
          tag: "mytag",
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
            onPressed: null,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("To first"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: and your `turns: animation` goes from 0 to ... ?

Comment: I don't know? All the code is in there to make the icon spin. How do I inspect / modify those values?

Comment: so what do you pass as `animation`? what is it?

Comment: I guess the animation is provided by the `Hero` or the `Navigator`. It is provided by flightShuttleBuilder.

Comment: before `return Scaffold(` call `print("animation: $animation");` - what do you see?

Comment: The variable animation does not exist there. It is provided by the `Hero` after the comment `Magic happens here` in the flightShuttleBuilder function.

Comment: ah ok, i see it now, so do it before `return RotationTransition(` - i bet it goes from [0..1]

Comment: `AnimationController#e78e9(◀ 0.907; for PageRouteBuilder<dynamic>)➩ProxyAnimation➩Cubic(0.40, 0.00, 0.20, 1.00)`

Comment: try: `Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 0.25).animate(...)` as your `RotationTransition` turns animation

Comment: That did the trick: `Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 0.5).animate(animation)` Thank you very much.

Comment: Any way to make it spin in the same direction on `Navigator.pop()`? It's now spinning backwards.

Comment: `ReverseAnimation`?

Comment: Works like a charm. Mind if I answer my own question here with a full code update? Or do you want to have a go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting the comments of [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) together: This is the updated code with an icon that spins half a circle to the same direction on push and pop:

```
flightShuttleBuilder: (
    BuildContext flightContext,
    Animation<double> animation,
    HeroFlightDirection flightDirection,
    BuildContext fromHeroContext,
    BuildContext toHeroContext,
  ) {
    Animation<double> newAnimation = 
      Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 0.5).animate(animation);

    if (flightDirection == HeroFlightDirection.pop) {
      newAnimation = ReverseAnimation(newAnimation);
    }

    return RotationTransition(
      turns: newAnimation,
      child: Material(
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        shadowColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        shape: CircleBorder(),
        child: toHeroContext.widget
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: good work , btw so now if it goes to 0.5 for half turn your initial 1.0 had to turn 360 degrees, not what you said 2 or more full turns...

Comment: True. Is seemed like more turns because the 'clear' cross has so many paws. I played it in slowmotion and it was in fact one turn.